# How does switch statement compares values?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Given the following sequence

```
switch(1) {
    case 1:
        cout << "first \n";
    case 2:
        cout << "second \n";
    default:
        cout << "Not first nor the second";
}
```

the output is

```
first 
second 
Not first nor the second
```

I'm expecting the output to be

```
first
```

so, how do values are compared? I know I didn't use the ***break*** statement, but isn't that just to save cpu time? How come the second case executes since there are two different integer values? What am I missing?

I'm using gcc 4.9.2 with -std=c++11 flag.

Comment: You're missing the `break;` at the end of each `case/default` block.

Comment: Doesn't your code answer your own question?

Comment: Read the `switch` statement definition. It states that processing starts from the appropriate label and proceeds until the `break` is met or the end of the `switch` block. You have no breaks, so the whole block is executed.

Comment: You may have read it else where that break should be used sparingly especially for new learners. However, this is one exceptional case. Switch statements comes with breaks. You have to use breaks to properly implement switch case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use `break` the code just continues. I guess it's a bit like a GOTO label in that sense. There are legitimate uses for omitting the `break` statement, such as when you want to do an `or` ...

```
switch(val) {
  case 1:
  case 2:
    // if val is 1 or 2...
    break;
  case 3:
    // if val == 3;
    break;
}
```